# Given $S_n = \sum \dots$ and $a_n = \sum \dots$ prove that $a_n = S_n + {1\over n\cdot n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let:
> $$
> \begin{align}
> S_n &= 2 + {1\over2!} + {1\over3!} + {1\over 4!} + \dots + {1\over n!} \\
> a_n &= 3 - {1\over 1\cdot2\cdot2!} - {1\over 2\cdot3\cdot3!} - \dots - {1\over (n-1)\cdot n\cdot n!}  
> \end{align}
> $$
> Prove that:
> $$
> a_n = S_n + {1\over n\cdot n!}
> $$

**My thought on this are:**

Manipulating the sums here would become pretty hard so I decided to use another approach. I've tried to look what the first terms of each sum are going to be in order to observe a pattern:

$$
\begin{align}
S_1 &= 2 \\
S_2 &= 2 + {1\over 2!} = S_1 + {1\over 2!} \\
S_3 &= 2 + {1\over 2!} + {1\over 3!} = S_2 + {1\over 3!}\\
&\vdots \\
S_{n+1} &= S_n + {1\over (n+1)!}
\end{align}
$$

A similar thing is done to $a_n$:

$$
a_{n+1} = a_n - {1\over n\cdot (n+1) \cdot (n+1)!}
$$

So potentially if we could find closed forms of both $S_n$ and $a_n$ it would become easier to reason about them.

By the way, I've observed both of the sums approach $e$ at infinity but from different sides. $S_n$ is starting from $2$ adding  more terms as $n$ grows, while $a_n$ starts from 3 and decreases the sum as $n$ grows. So that will be our initial conditions for both recurrences:

$$
S_1 = 2 \\
a_1 = 3
$$

The problem just reduced to finding closed forms of the recurrences. Both of them are non-homogenous and here is where I got stuck. Solving for homogenous part is easy since roots of both characteristic equations $\lambda_{a_n} = \lambda_{S_n} = 1$.

I couldn't find a particular solution for them. I've tried yet another approach expressing $S_{n+1}$ and $S_{n+2}$ trying to get rid of the $1\over (n+1)!$ or at least change its form so the guess for particular solution is more obvious.

> My questions are:
>
> 1. Is it even a valid approach to solve the problem?
> 2. If so then how could I find a closed form for the recurrences? Especially i'm interested in finding a particular solution. (Yet a complete flow is very appreciated and encourages learning by example)
> 3. Not sure how to phrase that better, but does there exist a table of "guesses" for particular solution of the recurrences in some form of $x_{n+1} = x_n + F(n)$. Like if the "free term" is a constant say $F(n) = 2$ then the guess for particular solution is some constant $B$.

Please excuse me if there is some vagueness or inaccuracy in the terminology, English is not my native language and I have almost no background in Maths.

Comment: It seems unlikely to find a simple closed form, because, as you noticed, the limit converges to $e$.

Comment: @user600464 is that because $e$ is irrational and that is why no "simple" formula for an irrational number may be obtained?

Comment: There is actually a simple formula, the limit $\frac{n^n}{(n- 1)^n}$. However, to compare to this sums, we would need many terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personal speaking, you could try your method, but i do not think this is promising. I would prove this by induction instead. For your question 3, you could check [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation), and you could try these solving techniques but you might go back to the expression given in the problem.

#### Proof by induction

$a_2 - S_2 = 3- 1/4 - (1 + 1/1! + 1/2!) $ [I think there is some typo in your expression of $S_n$]  $= 1/4 = 1/(2 \cdot 2!)]$. Suppose the equation holds for $n$. Then for $n+1$,
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1} - S_{n+1} &= a_n - S_n - \frac 1 {n(n+1) \cdot (n+1)!} - \frac 1{(n+1)!} \\
&=  \frac 1 {n!n }-\frac 1 {n(n+1) \cdot (n+1)!} - \frac 1{(n+1)!} \\
&= \frac 1 {(n+1)! (n+1)} \left( \frac {(n+1)^2}n -\frac 1n -(n+1) \right)\\
&= \frac 1 {(n+1)! (n+1)}.
\end{align*}
Thus the equation holds for all $n \geqslant 2$ by induction principle.

Answer (score 2):

$$ 
\begin{align} 
\color{red}{a_{n}-S_{n}} &=\left(3-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{(n-1)\cdot n\cdot n!}\right)-\left(2+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{n!}\right) \\[2mm] 
&=1-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{n!}\left(1+\frac{1}{(n-1)\cdot n}\right) =1-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{n!}\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right) \\[2mm] 
&=1-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{n}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right) =1-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)\cdot (n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n\cdot n!}\right) \\[2mm] 
&=1-\frac{1}{1\cdot1!}+\frac{1}{2\cdot2!}-\frac{1}{2\cdot2!}+\frac{1}{3\cdot3!}-\cdots+\frac{1}{n\cdot n!}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{n\cdot n!}}\quad\left\{\text{telescoping}\right\} 
\end{align} 
$$